# Call function in another View controller

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

In ViewController 1 I'm calling a function "changeButtonMessage" which is in ViewController 2 which should change the text of an UILabel. The function is being called (the NSLog works) but the label isn't being changed. Thanks for any help.

ViewController 1

```
loadingViewController *controller;
controller = [[loadingViewController alloc] init];
NSString *mymsg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Loading"]; 
[controller changeButtonMessage:mymsg];
```

ViewController 2

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *loadingtxt;
- (IBAction)changeButtonMessage:(id)sender;

@synthesize loadingtxt;

-(void)changeButtonMessage: (NSString*) newMessage {

     loadingtxt.text = newMessage;
     NSLog(@"Change label to %@",newMessage);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UIViewController.view property hasn't been accessed yet, you have created the object (alloc, init) but the view actually isn't loaded and it's subviews haven't been loaded.

loadingtxt is probably nil. You can verify that by debugging or NSLog it.

It won't be valid until loadView or viewDidLoad has been called on the UIViewController

How do you create your view controllers? StoryBoard ? Nib files?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The view controller is created in the ViewDidLoad of ViewController1 as ModalViewController  `loadingViewController *loadingView = [[[loadingViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        loadingView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self presentModalViewController:loadingView animated:NO];`

Comment: And how do you create your views in your view controller? Maybe you need to be using initWithNibName init method, if you have an associated nib file... Have you debugged it again and checked if loading txt is nil?